# Can tkinter use more than one theme at a time

Tags: python, tkinter, themes

Hi can anyone tell me if there is a way to use multiple themes with tkinter.

I have tried using separate tk instances and it works sort of, the window theme changes but the widgets like buttons etc don't respond to the tk.StringVar() so no text or image will appear in the widget.

I have tried using Topplevel windows but when I change the theme in one window all windows change.

I have also tried creating a separate thread for each Tk instance and that doesn't work either.

What I'd like to know is it possible to use more than one theme at a time.

The code below is base code for creating a window, all windows would use 
 similar code.

```
import json
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from zmq import Context
from zmq.backend.cython.constants import REQ

from tkbuilder.constants import REGISTER


class Client(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.id = id(self)
        self.cxt = Context()
        self.sock = self.cxt.socket(REQ)
        if self.sock:
            self.sock.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

    def register(self):
        req = json.dumps({
            'id': self.id,
            'req': REGISTER,
        })
        self.sock.send_string(req)
        req = json.loads(self.sock.recv())

        if req.get('auth'):
            win = self

            self.var = tk.StringVar()
            self.var.set(str(self.id))
            self.style = ttk.Style(win)
            self.style.theme_use('classic')
            win.title('User Login')

            btn = ttk.Button(win)
            btn.config(textvariable=self.var)
            btn.grid()
            ent = ttk.Entry(win)
            ent.config(textvariable=self.var)
            ent.grid()

            win.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you know any program which can run two themes at the same time ?

Comment: did you created separated instances in one script or in two separated scripts ? When you create two `Tk()` in one script then they are not isolated and they may have problem with `StringVar()` but if you run two script then system isolates them and they shouldn't have problem with `StringVar`

Comment: Why does that matter, I'm only trying to find out if it is possible.

Comment: I will try what you have suggested, thank you for your reply.

Comment: I never saw program which can run two themes at the same time (in one instance) so it can be answer for your question if tkinter can use two themes at the same time (in one instance). But two instances (isolated by system) should run different themes. Two `Tk()` in one script use shared memory so they may have problem to use different themes - it is not recomended to create two `Tk()` in one script.

Comment: You can build customizable themes using ttk syles or generating your own themes for the regular tk widgets. It just a lot of work.

Comment: Probably using `ttk` you could create different styles for different windows/subwindows.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and that doesn't work either, like I stated above the theme changes but the widget text and images don't appear when using tk.StringVar().

Comment: @furas yes you can set up many different style for different sets of labels, buttons, etcetera.

Comment: @DanielHuckson there is no way for us to help you without some code example. As it stands I am sure you can build custom themes as I have done so using both methods I mentioned above recently. Please provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without code we can't help more. I can only say as before - there are some problems with `StringVar` when you use two `Tk()` and/or two `mainloop()` in one script.

Comment: I have added the code I use to create a window, all windows would use a base like it.

Comment: Please provide an example that does not involve connection to a url. Just spoof the data. That said you are doing a couple things when building your window that is not normal so once you provide a "Testable" example we can fix it up. Also you are not applying a style to anything and that may be the problem you are seeing. You need to first define the style and name it then apply it to each set of ttk widgets you want to use it on.

Comment: I solved the problem, I was running each Tk instance in it's own thread. Instead of using threads I'm using a process and that works just how I wanted, thank you to those that replied.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want achieve exactly.

The "Style" in tkinter is a complex topic and a lot of work should be done.

I'll show you how to use two different styles in one window.
One is created by my self and the other is a default one.

Here an example with scrollbars:

```
#test_scrollbar_background_14_09_2014.py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def main():
    app = Tk()
    style = Style()

    style.element_create("My.Horizontal.Scrollbar.trough", "from", "default")

    style.layout("My.Horizontal.TScrollbar",
        [('My.Horizontal.Scrollbar.trough', {'children':
            [('Horizontal.Scrollbar.leftarrow', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
             ('Horizontal.Scrollbar.rightarrow', {'side': 'right', 'sticky': ''}),
             ('Horizontal.Scrollbar.thumb', {'unit': '1', 'children':
                 [('Horizontal.Scrollbar.grip', {'sticky': ''})],
            'sticky': 'nswe'})],
        'sticky': 'we'})])

    style.configure("My.Horizontal.TScrollbar", *style.configure("Horizontal.TScrollbar"))
    style.configure("My.Horizontal.TScrollbar", troughcolor="red")

    # Create and show a widget using the custom style
    hs = Scrollbar(app, orient="horizontal", style="My.Horizontal.TScrollbar")
    hs.place(x=5, y=5, width=150)
    hs.set(0.2,0.3)

    # Create and show a widget using the default style
    hs2 = Scrollbar(app, orient="horizontal", style="Horizontal.TScrollbar")
    hs2.place(x=5, y=150, width=150)
    hs2.set(0.2,0.3)

    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To describe each step I have to write a blog about Styles but you can figure out by your self what is going on. I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I was running each Tk instance in it's own thread. Instead of using threads I'm using a process and that works just how I wanted.